# Laravel Relationship through sub table

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a blog type website where the user can rate the posts. So the relationship is like this:

```
Blog -> blog_links; To Many fk = blog_id
User -> blog_links; To Many fk = user_id
```

I've tried these solutions and each time get a different error:

```
User::hasManyThrough(Blog::class, BlogLink::class);
```

That didn't work, so I tried query scope:

```
scopeWithLinksAndResorts($query) {
    return $query->with(['resorts' => function($q) {
        $q->ordered()->withLinks();
    }]);
}
```

That doesn't seem to return any results. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. And here's a table example:

blogs

```
id    Title    Text
1     Test     This is a test blog
```

users

```
id    email
1     test@test.com
```

blog_links

```
id    blog_id    user_id    rating
1     1          1          4
```

Now from this I want to get the blogs the user has rated and their rating. But as I said I get no results. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User model define the blog's relation

```
/**
 * 
 */
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blog', 'blog_links', 'user_id', 'blog_id')->withPivot('rating');
}
```

Then in your Blog model define the user's relation

```
/**
 * 
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'blog_links','blog_id', 'user_id');
}
```

To get all users with their blogs and rating you can do `\App\User::with('blogs')->get()`

I'm not sure if this is what you want but hope it helps.

Comment: Works wonderfully thanks. Didn't realise you could do a belongsToMany via a sub table, I thought that was what hasManyThrough was for? Or is that used in a different situation?

Comment: When you have many to many relationship there must be a pivot table and you set the relation in your models with  belongsToMany, see (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).  `The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation.` see (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)